# Empty dock and can't launch applications on Wayland

Tags: wayland

I read that Wayland is better than Xorg so I wanted to try it out. However, enabling it caused icons to be disappeared from the dock and show applications button does not respond as well. Should I update Wayland or is it my video card doesn't support it?

My video adapter is a poor Intel HD Graphics 5500. Ubuntu version is 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit.

Edit: I have changed my initial question completely after finding out I already have Wayland installed but was not using it.

Comment: If you just want to try it out, run a live session of a version/distro that uses it.   21.04 was just released and uses Wayland by default. If you switch to wayland on an installed system you might have problems switching back to X

Comment: @Nmath Why would they have problems switching back? It's only a matter of selecting one or the other at the login screen.

Comment: Install the other packages... it's not a real package (libwayland0), you need to use the sub packages (libwayland-*0)

Comment: Should I install all 6 of them?

Answer (score 1):

If I start Ubuntu with Wayland, I often don't seen any icons in teh docker and when I click applications, none appear. The docker seems to be repainted once I force a change to it, e.g. type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gnome-terminal` or open settings using the buttons on the top right corner.

After this, all seems to work.